# list not populating in c#

Tags: c#, list, model-view-controller, runtime

I have a view in MVC and on regeneration of form i am populating a list using forms collection.
but the list is not populating correctly and i am sure i am missing something in the list.
kindly check my code

```
    int noOfRows=Request.Form["rows"].ConvertToInt()};
    int noOfColmn=Request.Form["colmns"].ConvertToInt()};

    List<mymodel> list1= new List<mymodel>();


                  for (int roww = 1; roww < noOfRows; roww++)
                   {
                         list1=new List<mymodel>
                         {
                             new mymodel
    {
name=Request.Form["name-" + roww + ""].ConvertToInt() ,
rollno= Request.Form["rollno-" + roww + ""].ConvertToInt(),
                                 subjs=new List<mymodel>()}
                         };



     for (var colmn = 1; colmn < noOfColmn; colmn++)
                        {
                        var subjs= new List<mymodel> 
                        { new mymodel
                        {subjs=Request.Form["subj-" + roww + "-" + colmn + ""].ConvertToInt()}
                        };

                        }
                   }

                  ViewBag._list1 = list1;
```

Comment: Well, if at every loop you reinitialize list1 instead of adding the new model to the preexisting list you end your loop with only one model in the list (the last added)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should initialize the `list1` variable only outside the for loop and add elements to the same list when inside the loop.
Your current code reinitializes this `list1` variable at every loop. The internal loop does the same thing with the property `subjs` that appears to be another `List<mymodel>`.

I propose this code.
Of course, I am not able to test it, so let me know if this pseudocode fits your requirements.

```
int noOfRows=Request.Form["rows"].ConvertToInt()};
int noOfColmn=Request.Form["colmns"].ConvertToInt()};

// Create the list1 just one time here.
List<mymodel> list1= new List<mymodel>();
for (int roww = 1; roww < noOfRows; roww++)
{
     // creates an instance of mymodel
     mymodel m = new mymodel
     {
         name=Request.Form["name-" + roww + ""].ConvertToInt() ,
         rollno= Request.Form["rollno-" + roww + ""].ConvertToInt(),

         // create the internal list of mymodel
         subjs=new List<mymodel>()}
     };

     // add the model m to the list1 
     list1.Add(m);

     // loop to create the internal models
     for (var colmn = 1; colmn < noOfColmn; colmn++)
     {
          mymodel m2 = new mymodel
          {
               subjs=Request.Form["subj-" + roww + "-" + colmn + ""].ConvertToInt()}
          };

          // add all the subsequent models to the sublist internal to the first model
          m.subjs.Add(m2);
     }
}
ViewBag._list1 = list1;
```

Comment: a big thanks to you and yes you are right i was initializing the list every time.